# Repositioning a second select box under the first on low resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a asignment where i have to create a form that resizes nicely depending on the resolution.

Everything works as it should except for 2 select boxes that are position inline.

When the page gets resized, the second select box drops down and its label remains up.

I want the the second select box and its lable to go underneath the first select box and its lable togheter and aranged one under the other.

If possible i would like a solution in css only, preferably CSS2.

If i need to add something else or anything, please let me know and i will edit my post.

lable

```
            <div style="display:inline">

                <div style="display:inline">
                <p style="display:inline; padding-left: 5em">select #1</p>
                <select style="width:30%;margin-right: 8em"  name="experience">
                <option value="1" label=" "></option>
                <option value="2" label=" "></option>
                <option value="3" label=" "></option>
                <option value="4" label=" "></option>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div style="display:inline">
                <p style="padding-left: 1em; margin-right: 5em; display:inline">select #2</p>
                <select style="width:30%" name="experience">
                <option value="1" label=" "></option>
                <option value="2" label=" "></option>
                <option value="3" label=" "></option>
                <option value="4" label=" "></option>
                </select>
                </div>



            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline;` and give fixed `width` to the `select` element.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/e2qa9f44/)